# Is it possible to change page setup using Office JavaScript AddIn?

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins

I need to control Word document page setup using Word JavaScript AddIn.There is no direct API to achieve this. I tried to use insertOoxml to replace document content, but w:pgMar was ignored.

Is it possible at all? Can `context.document.body.style` be used for that purpose? Where can I get values that would be correct for `style` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not supported in the API. Please make sure you ask/vote for this in https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word

thanks!

Comment: This link is dead